# With R, how to subset a data set based on discountinuity breaks of one variable

Tags: r, subset, repeat

I am struggling to subset a data set according to one continous variable - let's call it "Time" - starting from 1 and incrementing by 1 each line (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..) but sometimes I get some missing values so I get some "jumps" (ex. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, **6**, **10**, 11, **12**, **20**, 21, 22, 23). These jumps are random so they don't get the same number of missing values in between. I want to split the dataset in multiples datasets when these "jumps" occur, so in my exemple it would give one data set from 1 to 6, another from 10 to 12, and another from 20 to 23.
Any idea how to do that ? That would be a great help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `group_split` after defining the consecutive groups with `cumsum(c(1, diff(Time) != 1))`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

tibble(Time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 23)) %>% 
  group_split(group = cumsum(c(1, diff(Time) != 1))) %>% 
  map(~ select(., -group)) 

[[1]]
# A tibble: 6 × 1
   Time
  <dbl>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
6     6

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 × 1
   Time
  <dbl>
1    10
2    11
3    12

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 × 1
   Time
  <dbl>
1    20
2    21
3    22
4    23
```